# Using non-public image from S3 as meta og:image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, facebook, amazon-s3, meta-tags

I would like to use non-public images from an S3 bucket in my site's meta tag.

My `<head>` looks like this:

```
<meta property="og:image"  content="<%= asset_path @list.image %>" />
```

And source like this:

```
<meta property="og:image"  content="//mybucket-main.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/asdflkj/myimage.jpg" />
```

My images render perfectly when I include them throughout the site:

`<%= image_tag @list.image %>` becomes

`<img src="//mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/asdflkj/myimage.jpg" alt="myimage" />`.

(Incidentally, it even renders in this post if I use the real `src`.)

I receive this error from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing:

`Object Invalid Value: Object at URL 'https://example.com/lists/1462' of type 'website' is invalid because the given value '//mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/image.jpg' for property 'og:image:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'.`

Please help!

Comment: Specify https or http and see if that helps.

Comment: Note also that if these images render, then they are **not**  "non-public" -- you're downloading them with no credentials in the URL.

Comment: hey, I just want to know whether you got the solution or not

Comment: Hey @Aks! I'm sorry, it's been so long and I'm not sure I ever figured this out, and I'm not working with S3 storage at present. Please comment if you do figure it out, as I could see this being useful to myself and others in the future.